# nested_form: children disappears on validation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I am able to validate children records but the records that have an error disappear after submitting the form.

```
class Deduction < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :parent_source, polymorphic: true, inverse_of: :deductions
    belongs_to :debt, polymorphic: true, inverse_of: :deductions
    validates :payee_id, presence: true
    validates :debt_id, presence: true
    validates_uniqueness_of :debt_id, scope: :parent_source
end


class Voucher < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :deductions, dependent: :destroy, as: :parent_source, inverse_of: :parent_source
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :deductions, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Comment: Post your controller and your form please.

Comment: Your voucher model  `has_many :deductions` but `accepts_nested_attributes_for :salary_deductions` how did you expect that to work?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your controller looks like but try adding the following line to the create action of the controller, if save fails:

@voucher.deductions.build unless @voucher.errors.any?